# How would I graph a line based on a degree measure in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-science

I am trying to draw a circle equally segmented into an indeterminate amount of "quadrants" based on the length of Array "categories" using the JavaScript library D3.js. An example is linked below, with 4 quadrants.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkwGP.png)

I am struggling with the method of drawing the grid lines dividing each of the "quadrants". My current approach is to draw a line per unique category, emanating from the origin (the center of the circle) to a point on the circumference of the circle. However, I am unsure as to (1) the method by which I can obtain the coordinates of the points on the circumference and (2) whether there is a better approach.

As of right now, I have the following code.

```
var svg = d3.select("svg#radar")
var radar = svg.append("g");
var grid = radar.append("g");
categories = Array(["cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3"])
function getX1 (i) {
  //get necessary coordinate
}
function getY1 (i) {
  //get necessary coordinate
}
for (var i; i < categories.length; i++) {
  grid.append("line")
    .attr("x1", getX1(i))
    .attr("y1", getY1(i))
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", config.colors.grid)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Just use trigonometry (sin and cosine) like so:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg#radar")
var radar = svg.append("g");
var grid = radar.append("g");
categories = Array(["cat_1", "cat_2", "cat_3"])
function getX1 (i) {
    var deg = (360 / categories.length) * i; 
    var percent_of_circle = deg / 360
    var radians = percent_of_circle * 2 * Math.PI
    return 400 * Math.cos(radians);
}
function getY1 (i) {
    var deg = (360 / categories.length) * i; 
    var percent_of_circle = deg / 360
    var radians = percent_of_circle * 2 * Math.PI
    return 400 * Math.sin(radians);    }
for (var i; i < categories.length; i++) {
  grid.append("line")
    .attr("x1", getX1(i))
    .attr("y1", getY1(i))
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", 0)
    .style("stroke", config.colors.grid)
    .style("stroke-width", 1);
}
```